# Параметр из респонаса передается в реквест, но не выполняется

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Для одного из request'ов добавила `BeanShell PreProcessor`, в котором проинициализировала массив, положила одно из значений в переменную. В *Debug Sampler* вижу, что значение успешно записалось в переменную. Также эта переменная успешно передается в запрос №2, но ответ я получаю совсем не тот, что ожидала, вида:

```
//EX[2,1,["com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException/3936916533","Type 'mydomain.dto.settings.filters.ResultDetailsFilterPattern' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer. For security purposes, this type will not be deserialized."],0,7]
```

Таким образом, запрос не выполняется. что не так? в логах пусто. прошу помощи, ибо не могу решить эту проблему весь день

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так проблема у вас в сервере, а не в Jmeter - если запрос был отправлен, а ответ не тот - нужно копать сервер. Быть может нужно куки передавать или кастомные заголовки. Снимите снифером / прокси отправляемые запросы с вашего приложения / сайта и посмотрите в чем отличие от вашего запроса. Можно сделать [запись](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) ваших шагов.